# Select criteria using a case expression in where clause based on other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm trying to return the count of column Grade based on column Level. If column Level equals "1" then I want to count all rows for column ID where Grade is either "A", "B", "C", or "D". If column "Level" equals "2" then I want to count all rows for column ID where Grade is either "A", "B", or "C",

Example Table:

[image]

Example output:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what errors/problems are you encountering?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provided sample queries of what you tried and some insight to your schema (particularly your table names for when we provide example solution code). I think that's why some people are giving your question a negative score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ID,SUM(CASE WHEN Level=1 AND Grade IN ('A','B','C','D') THEN 1 
            WHEN Level=2 AND Grade IN ('A','B','C') THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS GradeCount
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a CASE expression is needed, or even wanted in this case. Try using UNION for your two "cases":

```
SELECT
  1 AS ID,
  COUNT( 1 ) AS GradeCount
FROM
  LevelsAndGrades
WHERE
  ID = 1 AND
  Grade IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' )
UNION
SELECT
  2 AS ID,
  COUNT( 1 ) AS GradeCount
FROM
  LevelsAndGrades
WHERE
  ID = 2 AND
  Grade IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `case when` expression and the `sum` aggregate function.

Here is the full sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Grades ([Id] int, [Level] int, [Number] int, [Grade] nchar(1));

INSERT INTO #Grades VALUES
(1,1,100,'A'),
(1,1,101,'B'),
(1,1,102,'C'),
(1,1,103,'D'),
(1,1,104,'F'),

(2,2,300,'A'),
(2,2,301,'B'),
(2,2,302,'C'),
(2,2,303,'D'),
(2,2,304,'F');


SELECT Id, SUM(CASE WHEN  [Level] = 1 AND [Grade] IN ('A','B','C','D')   THEN 1 
                    WHEN  [Level] = 2 AND [Grade] IN ('A','B','C')       THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 
               END) 
FROM #Grades
GROUP BY [Id];
```